# XFile Sharing: I am not able to install xfile sharing free version on my Linux server

Tags: file-sharing

I have download the xfile sharing free script and try to install that according to the installation file. But I am not able to run the script.

I have downloaded demo version from https://sibsoft.net/xfilesharing.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permisions of install.cgi to 755 & try installing it again.
Regards